# Create a publicly accessible license report of dependencies in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, sbt

While building the distribution of a Play Framework project, I'd like to generate a list of dependencies and their licenses and make that publically accessible.

Using [sbt-license-report](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-license-report) and the `sbt dumpLicenseReport` command, I can create a generate HTML, CSV and markdown formatted reports in `/target/license-report`, which is a very good start.

What I'd really like to achieve is every time I run `sbt dist`:

- it automatically runs `dumpLicenseReport` first
- places the results at `/public/license-report` rather than at `/target/license-report`.

As the files are placed at `/public/license-report`, they would be built into the assets jar at `lib/com.example.project-name-x.y.z-assets.jar` within the distribution zip, thus making them publically accessible at `https://servername/assets/license-report`.

So my question is twofold:

1. How do I get `dumpLicenseReport` to run as part of `sbt dist` (at the beginning)?
2. How do I get `sbt dumpLicenseReport` to output the files in my favored place (`/public/license-report`)?

Comment: How about creating a script that does exactly what you said? And instead of running `sbt dist`, just run `./myscript`. The script would basically run `sbt dumpLicenseReport`, then `mv` to move your report, then `sbt dist`

Comment: ‍♀️ Well, yes. That seems obvious now. Thanks.

Comment: ...but it does complicate matters on my build server, so my question still stands.